# Login with username or email

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, email

So I'm trying to let the user login with their username or email, and password. Here's my query

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE  (username = ':username' OR email = ':email') AND password = :pass
```

The problem is how do I bind the values? Here's all of my code

```
$st = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE  (username = ':username' OR email = ':email') AND password = :pass");
$st->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->bindValue(':username', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->bindValue(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$st->execute();
$rows = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

As you can see I use `$email` twice, `$email` is

```
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Any help would be great. With my current code I get this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in /Users/matt/Desktop/Mail/l.php:27 Stack trace: #0 /Users/matt/Desktop/Mail/l.php(27): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /Users/matt/Desktop/Mail/l.php on line 27

**EDIT** When doing @Deele's suggest way I get

> Notice: Undefined index: name in /Users/matt/Desktop/Mail/l.php on line 60

And

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/matt/Desktop/Mail/l.php:60) in /Users/matt/Desktop/Mail/l.php on line 60

Line 60 is `header('Location: profile.php?username='.$_SESSION['name']);`

Comment: For bound parameter names, don't use enclosing quotes, they are not required.

Comment: So instead of this `$st->bindValue(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);` do this? `$st->bindValue(:pass, $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);` @Deele

Comment: No, use `SELECT * FROM users WHERE  (username = :username OR email = :email) AND password = :pass`. In addition to that, you should find user by login and only after it has been found, retrieve it and then, compare passwords using php, like this `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username OR email = :username LIMIT 1`

Comment: I still get the same error. Is this a suggestion or an actual answer? @Deele

Comment: The error you are talking about does not match the code you are showing here, that is why I don't think, this is actual answer to original question. I don't know which is "27th line" to start with. I can't reproduce error you encountered, there is something more.

Comment: did you try anything like:
$username = $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
and then
$st->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: What is line 27 in `/Users/matt/Desktop/Mail/l.php` ??

Comment: I've gotten past that issue. When I now use _your_ code I get `Notice: Undefined index: name in /Users/idrisk/Desktop/Mail/l.php on line 60` and line 60 is `header('Location: profile.php?username='.$_SESSION['name']);` @Deele

Comment: `$st->execute();`, check the above comment @HamedKamrava

Comment: Check my updated @adolfotcar

Comment: This is beyond original problem already. That "name" error is another case that has nothing to do with MySQL/PDO.

Comment: Well I only seem to get it when trying your method.... @Deele

Comment: The index error means that you're trying to access a member of an array which doesn't exists, check your SESSION?
The header() error is because you can't change the location after something has been already outputted....but as @Deele said, it's another issue

Comment: It looks like the suggestion by @Deele has fixed the problem and your script is now carrying on running as the user has now successfully logged on. Which has allowed it to hit the next error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
// Try to find user
try {
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :login OR email = :login LIMIT 1');
    $sth->execute(array(':login' => $_POST['email']));
    $user = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Login error: '.$e->getMessage();
}
// If user was found, authenticate it by comparing passwords
if ($user && isset($user['password']) && md5($user['password']) == $_POST['password']) {
    echo 'Login success.';
}
else {
    echo 'Login failed.';
}
```

*Note: Not tested*

Do this separate from other code, to test, if it works for you. Preferably, create a class for user like `class User { public static function findByLogin($login) { /* ... */ } }`, or at least single function like `user_findByLogin($login) { /* ... */ } }` so it would be easier to test and debug your own code. After that, add another method/function that does auth process, to compare passwords.